# mean of the values in interquartile range in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
above25percentile=df.loc[df["order_amount"]>np.percentile(df["order_amount"],25)]
below75percentile=df.loc[df["order_amount"]<np.percentile(df["order_amount"],75)]
interquartile=above25percentile & below75percentile
print(interquartile.mean())
```

can't seem to get the mean here. any thoughts?

Comment: Please show a sample dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You attempt to compute `interquartile` as a boolean mask based on the `&` operator, but its components are Series containing values from the ranges. While the two series are likely to be similar sizes, `&` will not give you an intersection of their indices. If they were boolean masks, in your subsequent usage, you'd be taking the mean of a bunch of zeros and ones, which is going to be 0.5 (the ratio of data that falls within the IQR as a matter of fact).

First, compute `interquartile` as a proper mask. Pandas has its own [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) method, which, like `np.percentile` and siblings, accepts multiple percentiles simultaneously. You can combine that with [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to get your mask more efficiently:

```
interquartile = df['order_amount'].between(*df['order_amount'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]))
```

You can apply the mask to the column and take the mean like this:

```
df.loc[interquartile, 'order_amount'].mean()
```

Comment: i) *`interquartile`is a boolean mask in your computation,* No, it's not; notice the `df.loc`'s in front of `above25percentile` and the other one (unless the `df` itself is of all booleans, which is highly unlikely but who knows). ii) *If* `interquartile` was a boolean mask as you described,  *df['order_amount'][interquartile]* is bad practice; `df.loc[interquartile, "order_amount"]` is preferred.

Comment: @Neither. This is what happens when I don't run my code

Comment: @Neither. Updates made.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *its components are Series of likely unequal dimensions*? How could the series have "different dimensions" if they are in *a* dataframe (if the operation succeeds at all)?

Comment: @Neither. As written in the question, and you emphasized, `above25percentile` and `below75percentile` are unlikely to have the same index.

Comment: @Neither. Updated the prose a bit. They actually are the same size (usually at least). You can technically get an off-by-one or more by playing with repeated values.

Comment: I see; but pandas forms the result of `&` with the index being the union of that of operands so "unequal" dimensions kind of gather together. But with the edit I think it's clear, I leave now.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
above25percentile = df["order_amount"]>np.percentile(df['order_amount'],25)
below75percentile = df['order_amount']<np.percentile(df['order_amount'],75)
print(df.loc[above25percentile & below75percentile, 'order_amount'].mean())
```

Or you can use `between`:

```
df.loc[df['order_amount'].between(np.percentile(df['order_amount'], 25),
                                  np.percentile(df['order_amount'], 75),
                                  inclusive='neither'), 'order_amount'].mean()
```

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'order_amount': range(0, 10)})
print(df)

# Output
   order_amount
0             0  # Excluded
1             1  # "
2             2  # "
3             3
4             4  # mean <- (3 + 4 + 5 + 6) / 4 = 4.5
5             5
6             6
7             7  # Excluded
8             8  # "
9             9  # "
```

Output:

```
>>> df.loc[df['order_amount'].between(np.percentile(df['order_amount'], 25),
                                  np.percentile(df['order_amount'], 75),
                                  inclusive='neither'), 'order_amount'].mean()
4.5
```

Comment: you need "and" not "or"? `above25percentile & below75percentile`

Comment: `between` returns a mask. You won't get a meaningful result from taking the mean of a mask. Actually it's meaningful, but not at all what OP wants.

Comment: Your first snippet is not respecting the column, only the rows.

Comment: I didn't test my code either.